# How to handle long title string for backBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift

I changed back `button` text with below code, here domain is the `string` of a `url` which may be a very long string. So how to display it correctly when it is very long?

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: domain, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton.
```

Comment: What is the criteria of "correct" when the string is very long for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit set to the back button title. This limit cannot be determined through the Apple doc. If you try to set the longer title than specified limit Apple has then this longer title will be replaced with "Back" title. And it hardly makes sense to have the back button title that big, it really hampers the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not use a long title, look how Apple does it, when title is too long then they use a generic `back` title. You will not get a good result from a long back button title no matter how you implement it...

Comment: Based on the character count of the title you want to display, you should play with this value to see when it is ok to display the title and when it is too long

Comment: How to detect the title will exceed the Screen? For different device, the width is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
let barButton = UIButton()
    barButton.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:30, height:30)
    barButton.setTitle(“BarButtonTest”, for: .normal)
    barButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    barButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    barButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapBarButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: barButton)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton


If above answer not solve your problem then instead of using navigation bar use custom view as Navigation Bar using autolayout and take button inside it, set your title accordingly.
```